# How to round off decimal values to the nearest highest digit

Tags: rounding

How to round off decimal values to the nearest highest digit?

For an ex:

```
13.799 => 13.80
13.023 => 13.02
27.8555 => 27.86
```

Is there any algorithm present on this?

Comment: What APIs and/or languages are you using?

Comment: You've only tagged your question as XML, which is a markup, not a programming, language.  Without additional context, your question is too underspecified to answer.

Comment: You should read [ask]. Your question isn't clear. You've got two examples round from 3 to 2 decimals, then one from 4 to 2. Are you asking to round to 2 decimal places? If so, what kind of rounding do you want?

Comment: The tags for `C#` and `ASP.Net` were incorrectly added during an edit without any evidence. Author needs to clarify the language they want an answer in.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Math.Round(decimal)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Math_Round_System_Decimal_) or the overload which takes a [MidpointRounding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Math_Round_System_Decimal_System_MidpointRounding_) argument.

```
Math.Round(value)
```

Another option is to use `decimal.Ceiling(13.023)`

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of XPath, you can round to 2 decimal digits using `round(., 2)`.

Answer (score 0):

as Nouman suggested the [Math.Round(value)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Math_Round_System_Decimal_) is the right choise.

In you Needs you could use something like this:

```
   public static void Main()
   {
      //Array where the Information is stored
      double[] values = { 13.799, 13.023, 27.8555 };
      //for each value in the array
      foreach (double value in values)
         //write it to the console like unrounded-value => rounded-value 
         //specify on how many Digit you want to round
         Console.WriteLine("{0} => {1}", value, Math.Round(value, 2));

   }
```

The example displays the following output:

```
13.799 => 13.80
13.023 => 13.02
27.8555 => 27.86
```

Additional Note:

The ***Decimal*** value of 4.5 rounds to 4 rather than 5, because this overload uses the default ToEven convention.

Comment: Thanks Julian! your inputs were helpful.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. Feel to upvote and accept it as answer. Have a nice day